# How do I convert a DataTable to a jagged array in C#?

Tags: c#, numpy, datatable, jagged-arrays

I'm new to C# and I can't find an example of this anywhere (although I have seen similar examples but the casting was ToString, whereas in my case I want arrays of integers). I have a DataTable object,

```
DataTable results = dbCon.ExecuteQuery("my query");

int m = results.Rows.Count; 
int n = results.Columns.Count;
```

I want a jagged array consisting of n one-dimensional arrays (each array being a column of the DataTable (`results`, in this case).

```
int[][] jagged = new int[n][];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                jagged[i] = new int[m];
                //var coli = results.Columns.Cast<Array>().Select(column => Convert.ToInt32(column)).ToArray();
            //jagged[i] = coli;
        }
```

I've tried a few things (for example what I commented out) but I'm quite stuck now.

If anyone knows how to do this, please post something! Thanks!

Also, to be more specific, I'd really like to use a function like the one NumPy provides to Python... `dataSet = np.array(dataList).astype('float')`. Double for loops are not in my best interest as my DataTable is large.

Comment: Does each row have a different number of columns? Or are you wanting to turn the contents of the column into an array of integers?

Comment: I have n columns each with m rows.. basically I just want a matrix. But I read an article talking about performance and saying that jagged arrays are best for matrix multiplication. http://www.heatonresearch.com/content/choosing-best-c-array-type-matrix-multiplication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you also need to make the array of type object.  The `DataTable` `DataRow` holds things of type `object`, therefore that is what you need to store them as in your jagged array.

I think this will work:

```
DataTable table = dbCon.ExecuteQuery("my query");
int rowCount = table.Rows.Count;
int colCount = table.Columns.Count;

object[][] objs = new object[colCount][];

for (int currentColumn = 0; currentColumn < colCount; currentColumn++)
{
    objs[currentColumn] = new object[rowCount];
    for (int currentRow = 0; currentRow < rowCount; currentRow++)
    {
        objs[currentColumn][currentRow] = table.Rows[currentRow][currentColumn];
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know about Python - but I do know that when I do this: `MessageBox.Show(objs[1][1].ToString());` I get a legit value from the jagged array.  If you don't like the double `for` loop you could always break it up into two different method calls - each with a `for` loop in it.  That way it at least _looks_ better..

Comment: Rather than extracting the value to your program, try putting a `break` in the code after the jagged array has filled and look at the array and see if the values are in it.  That way you can at least tell whether your issue is coming from when you display the value or when the value populates..

Comment: Okay, this works. One question before I give you points and mark this question as answered.. Is there really no way to do this like I can in Python (i.e. dataSet = np.array(dataList).astype('float'))? I really don't like this double for loop in my code. Just read your comments and okay I guess I'm good for now.

Comment: Like I said, I have never dealt with Python - but I am glad that I could help somewhat at least! Have a good one.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you already have this. Try:

```
results.Rows[rowIndex][columnIndex]
```

To get it into jagged array, you may go for simple *for* loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < results.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < results.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        jagged[i][j] = results.Rows[i][j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want just using LINQ against the `DataTable`.  For each column in the `DataTable`, you need to iterate over the rows and select that column.  You need to call `Cast()` to `Select()` on the columns and `AsEnumerable()` to be able to `Select()` on the rows:

```
int[][] jagged = results.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
    .Select(
        col => results.AsEnumerable()
            .Select(row => row.Field<int>(col))
            .ToArray()
    ).ToArray();
```

Comment: I'd like to use your post b/c the table that I'm querying from is very large so double for loops are not in my best interest. But I tried this and got an InvalidCastException. The problem seems to be at row => row.Field<int>. Maybe you missed something in your post or I'm mis-using your post. Really, I'd just like to do something like the NumPy package allows you to do in Python (i.e.  dataSet = numpy.array(dataList).astype('float'))

Comment: @eTothEipiPlus1 I would guess that you have extra columns in your `DataTable` that are not `int`s.  You could filter the columns with a `.Where(...)` before the first select, so you only get the columns you want.

Comment: @eTothEipiPlus1 Alternatively, change the array to `object[][]` and use `row[col]` instead of `row.Field<int>(col)` and you'll get all the columns, regardless of type.  Not sure it avoids double loops though - the nested `Select`s will do the looping.